# jQuery Mouse over and out event not worked

Tags: jquery, rollover

I have been trying to get this code to work for a while now and cannot figure out what is wrong. It is for a tri-state rollover with images. (I know that I can do this with CSS so please do not answer with that.) The goal is, I am trying to learn jquery and as part of the learning, I am trying to figure out what I am missing here.

What I am having issues with is when you do the mouseover and mouseout events the buttons highlight correctly. However, when I click on a button then click on another button all the buttons that I click stay on. I need to be able to toggle the on the state as on click each image like a typical tab control.

I know that there are better ways of doing this, but I am really trying to learn what I did wrong and I am extremely frustrated. So if there is anyone out there that can help specifically fix the code I am posting I would really appreciate it. Again, I know that this could be accomplished with certain CSS techniques, but I would like to understand what I am doing wrong here.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var clicked_obj;
        $("#nav a").mouseover(function () {
            if ($(this).data("clicked")) { return; }
            $(this).children("img").each(function () {
                this.src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/_off.gif$/ig, "_on.gif");
            });
        }).mouseout(function () {
            if ($(this).data("clicked")) { return; }
            $(this).children("img").each(function () {
                this.src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/_on.gif$/ig, "_off.gif");
            });
        }).click(function () {
            if (clicked_obj) {
                $(clicked_obj).removeData("clicked").mouseout();
            }
            clicked_obj = this;
            $(this).data("clicked", true);
            $(this).children("img").each(function () {
                this.src = $(this).attr("src").replace(/_off.gif$/ig, "_clk.gif");
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/inbox_wrilogo.gif" width="143" height="30" alt="logo" border="0" /></div>
        <div id="tab"><a href="#"><img src="images/nav_support_off.gif" width="75" height="22" alt="Support" name="support" border="0" /></a></div>
        <div id="tab"><a href="#"><img src="images/nav_acct_off.gif" width="75" height="22" alt="My Account" name="acct" border="0" /></a></div>
        <div id="tab"><a href="#"><img src="images/nav_inbox_off.gif" width="75" height="22" alt="Inbox" name="inbox" border="0" /></a></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it is advisable to put your topic title in the form of a question.  The more specific the better.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What are they?

Comment: We need to see the HTML code to understand what's going on here.

Comment: I added the HTML and fixed the subject tks.

Comment: Gabe no errors just when I click a button they all stay active instead of toggling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do exactly what you think you should do :) (the beauty of jquery :)... remove the selected state from the previously clicked button when you click on a new one.... Here's a version that uses styles instead of images, but you should be able to change the add/remove class to changing the images

```
var sel;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav a")
    .mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("mouseOver");
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("mouseOver");
    })
    .click(function() {
        if( sel != null ) {
            $(sel).removeClass("selected");
        }
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        sel = this;
    });
});
```

Comment: can you give me an example of how you would use images. I tries several and I am unable to get it to work that way I would like.